# How to make Uncrustify force blank lines between functions?

Tags: uncrustify

I've been working on my uncrustify config for a few hours now and I'm very close to having it the way I need it. However, I can't find an option to control newlines between function bodies. Uncrustify always removes blank lines between functions, but I'd like to enforce one blank line. Currently I get this:

Input:

```
void foo() {
  std::cout << "foo!" << std::endl;
}

void bar() {
  std::cout << "bar!" << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
void foo() {
  std::cout << "foo!" << std::endl;
}
void bar() {
  std::cout << "bar!" << std::endl;
}
```

In my case, I'd like to preserve (force!) the blank line in the input. Is there an option to control this?

Answer (score 10):

Epiphany - I was miscounting 'newlines'. The configuration option for this is:

```
# The number of newlines after '}' of a multi-line function body
nl_after_func_body                       = 2        # number
```

I originally set this to 1. However, Uncrustify includes the newline on the line containing the brace (`}`). Setting this to 2 gives the desired result.